# Hilbert class field whose class number is 1.

Tags: number-theory

How to describe Hilbert class field of an imaginary quadratic field whose class number is 1 ? What happens to unramification at finite places ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $K$ has class number one, then the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID, hence an UFD. In this case, $K$ is its own Hilbert class field - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field). Indeed, a number field $K$ with class number $1$ cannot have an abelian unramified extension larger than $K$ itself.